# Can I write LLVM pass using add_llvm_library, not add_llvm_loadable_module?

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'd write new transform pass related to some function optimization, and contribute it into LLVM.
But [Writing an LLVM Pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) was described using as dynamic LLVM loadable modules (.so extensions).

I want to write LLVM pass using `add_llvm_library`, not `add_llvm_loadable_module` in `CMakeLists.txt`.
Can I do it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm unsure why would you want this, [this documentation section](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#cmake-out-of-source-pass) probably answers your question. Just replace `add_library()` call from that code snippet with `add_llvm_library()`.

You can also develop your pass in-tree. For this, place your sources somewhere in `lib/Analysis` and then list them in `lib/Analysis/CMakeLists.txt`. This way your pass would be compiled into LLVM itself.

From my POV it is much more convenient to develop a pass out of source tree using `add_llvm_loadable_module()`, though.